# Creating jar binding for JSOUP library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to create binding library of jsoup-1.7.3.jar file. I have followed the documentation to bind the java library from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/). But I am getting following error while binding the library

```
Error CS0535: 'Org.Jsoup.Helper.HttpConnection' does not implement interface member 'Org.Jsoup.IConnection.Response()'
Error CS0535: 'Org.Jsoup.Nodes.Attribute' does not implement interface member 'Java.Util.IMapEntry.SetValue(Java.Lang.Object)'
Error CS0738: 'Org.Jsoup.Nodes.Attribute' does not implement interface member 'Java.Util.IMapEntry.Key'. 'Org.Jsoup.Nodes.Attribute.Key' cannot implement 'Java.Util.IMapEntry.Key' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Java.Lang.Object'.
```

similar 116 such errors are present.
My current metada.xml looks like follows:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.jsoup.parser']/class[@name='Parser']/constructor[@name='Parser' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder']]" name="managedName">customone</attr>     
   <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.jsoup.parser']/class[@name='TreeBuilder']" name="visibility">public</attr>  
   <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.jsoup.parser']/class[@name='Token']" name="visibility">public</attr>  
   <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.jsoup.parser']/class[@name='ParseErrorList']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

I totally lost about how to get rid of all this error and get my jsoup dll file so that i can use it in my other project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is using a native .net HTML parsing library instead totally out of question?

Comment: I tried using Nuget NSoup 0.8.0  in my project , but it is giving me following error "Could not install package 'NSoup 0.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author." .. what could be wrong ?

Comment: I'm not into C# and won't be an helping hand for your issue here. However as of  this comment writing, the latest Jsoup version is **1.8.3** or there may be a small typo in the post.